# spring cloud stream app image-viewer for kafka not found

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I was trying to implement the example given in the blog ([found here](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/real-time-object-detection-with-spring-cloud-stream)) for real time object detection using spring cloud data flow but could not download / find the image-viewer sink app as mentioned in the blog which super imposes the image with object detection done using tensorflow.

I am trying to bulk import applications from below bit.ly URL : **bit.ly/Darwin-SR1-stream-applications-kafka-maven**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image-viewer` from the blog is not an official sink application. It is available for experimentation from a personal repo, though.

Christian's [repository](https://github.com/tzolov/computer-vision#spring-cloud-stream-computervision-applications) includes the collection of all the utility Apps pertaining to Tensorflow and there's an easy getting-started guide to get this up and running on your environment.